# If $(\mu_t)_{t\in I}$ and $(\mu_t\ast\nu_t)_{t\in I}$ are tight, then $(\nu_t)_{t\in I}$ is tight

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $E$ be a metric $\mathbb R$-vector space, $I$ be a nonempty set and $(\mu_t)_{t\in I},(\nu_t)_{t\in I}$ be families of nonnegative finite measures on $\mathcal B(E)$.

[We can show](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3961494/47771) that if $(\mu_t)_{t\in I}$ and $(\nu_t)_{t\in I}$ are tight$^1$ and bounded in total variation norm, then the family of convolutions $(\mu_t\ast\nu_t)_{t\in I}$ is tight and bounded in total variation norm as well.

> Now I would like to show the converse: If $(\mu_t)_{t\in I}$ and $(\mu_t\ast\nu_t)_{t\in I}$ are tight, then $(\nu_t)_{t\in I}$ is tight. (Most probably we need to impose a boundedness assumption on $(\mu_t)_{t\in I}$ and on $(\mu_t\ast\nu_t)_{t\in I}$ or even a priori on $(\nu_t)_{t\in I}$.)

For the moment, I'm only able to prove the claim assuming that the $\mu_t,\nu_t$ are probability measures. Under this assumption, the proof goes as follows:

Let $\varepsilon>0$. Since $(\mu_t)_{t\in I}$ and $(\mu_t\ast\nu_t)_{t\in I}$ are tight, there is a compact $K\subseteq E$ with $$\sup\left(\sup_{t\in I}\mu_t(K^c),\sup_{t\in I}(\mu_t\ast\nu_t)(K^c)\right)<\varepsilon\tag1.$$ Now $K-K$ is compact and \begin{equation}\begin{split}1-\varepsilon<(\mu_t\ast\nu_t)(K)&=\underbrace{\int_K\mu_t({\rm d}x)\nu_t(\underbrace{K-x}_{\subseteq\:K-K})}_{\le\:\nu_t(K-K)}+\underbrace{\int_{K^c}\mu_t({\rm d}x)\underbrace{\nu_t(K-x)}_{\le\:1}}_{<\:\varepsilon}\\&<\nu_t(K-K)+\varepsilon\end{split}\tag2\end{equation} for all $t\in I$, which immediately yields $$\nu_t(K-K)>1-2\varepsilon\;\;\;\text{for all }t\in I\tag3.$$

> Can we drop the probability measure assumption?

### **EDIT**

I'm not able to obtain the claim, even with the help of the answer below. If $\varepsilon>0$, the goal is to show that $$\nu_t(E)-\nu_t(K-K)=\nu_t((K-K)^c)<\varepsilon\tag4.$$ If I'm choosing all the constants as generic as possible, we obtain $$\mu_t(E)\le c_1\tag5$$ $$\mu_t(K^c)\le k_1(\varepsilon)\tag6$$ $$(\mu_t\ast\nu_t)(K)<c_1\nu_t(K-K)+c_2k_1(\varepsilon)\tag6$$ $$\mu_t(E)\ge\alpha_1\tag7$$ $$(\mu_t\ast\nu_t)(E)\le c_3\tag8$$ $$\nu_t(E)\le\frac{c_3}{\alpha_1}=:c_2\tag9$$ $$(\mu_t\ast\nu_t)(E)\ge\alpha_3\tag{10}$$ $$\nu_t(E)\ge\frac{\alpha_3}{c_1}\tag{11}$$ $$(\mu_t\ast\nu_t)(K^c)<k_3(\varepsilon)$$

The assumptions that I'm imposing is that $(\mu_t)$ and $(\mu_t\ast\nu_t)$ are bounded above (by $c_1$ and $c_3$) and below (by $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_3$) in total variation norm and are tight (so that we can find $K$ for arbitrary $k_1(\varepsilon)$ and $k_3(\varepsilon)$).

In order to obtain the claim we need to choose $k_1(\varepsilon)$ and $k_3(\varepsilon)$ such that $(4)$ holds. From everything above, we obtain $$\nu_t(E)-\nu_t(K-K)<\frac{c_3}{\alpha_1}-\frac{\alpha_3}{c_1}+\frac{c_3}{\alpha_1c_1}k_1(\varepsilon)+\frac1{c_1}k_3.(\varepsilon)\tag{12}$$ Even if we simplify this by assuming $\alpha_1=\alpha_3$, $c_1=c_3$ and $k_1(\varepsilon)=k_3(\varepsilon)$, the equation $$\frac{c_3}{\alpha_1}-\frac{\alpha_3}{c_1}+\frac{c_3}{\alpha_1c_1}k_1(\varepsilon)+\frac1{c_1}k_3.(\varepsilon)=\varepsilon\tag{13}$$ doesn't seem to admit a solution $(k_1(\varepsilon),k_3(\varepsilon))$ with **positive** $k_1(\varepsilon)$ and $k_3(\varepsilon)$; **unless** $\frac{c_3}{\alpha_1}-\frac{\alpha_3}{c_1}\ge0$; which clearly doesn't need to be the case (it is clearly the case for probability measures though ...)

---

$^1$ Remember that a family $\mathcal F$ of finite signed measures on $\mathcal B(E)$ is called *tight* if for all $\varepsilon>0$, there is a compact $K\subseteq E$ such that $$\sup_{\mu\in\mathcal F}|\mu|(K^c)<\varepsilon.$$

Comment: You probably want to add some assumption on $\mu_t$ to prevent me taking $\mu_t = 0$ for all $t$ which would mean the hypotheses on $\mu_t, \mu_t \ast \nu_t$ would be satisfied for arbitrary choices of $\nu_t$. A less trivial example in this direction is to consider $\mu_n = n^{-1} \mu$, $\nu_n = n \mu$ for some fixed measure $\mu$.

Comment: @RhysSteele Thank you for your comment. Yes, I know. Excluding $\mu_t=0$ was on my mind as I wrote the question, but I really have no idea which assumption is suitable.

Comment: The less trivial example shows that $mu_t = 0$ isn't the real problem. The problem is that $\mu_t$ can have vanishing total mass which allows $\mu_t \ast \nu_t$ to have controlled mass whilst the mass of $\nu_t$ blows up in a way that prevents tightness. Your proof will work more generally if $\sup_t \nu_t(E) < \infty$. I can't think of a more natural assumption than this that excludes my less trivial example.

Comment: @RhysSteele If $\nu_t$ is nonnegative, then the total variation norm of $\nu_t$ is simply $\nu_t(E)$ and hence your assumption $\sup_t\nu_t(E)<\infty$ is precisely the boundedness in total variation norm I've written about in the question. I don't know how we can extend my proof to this more general case, but it seems like you do. So, it would be great if you could provide an answer. Maybe it does work for finite signed measures with $\sup_t|\nu_t|(E)<\infty$ as well?

Comment: @RhysSteele Really interested in this one. Please let me know if you have an idea.

Answer (score 1):

My counter-example in the comments will still work. Let $\mu_n = n^{-1} \delta_0$ and let $\nu_n = \delta_n$. Then all of the hypotheses in the question are satisfied but $\nu_n$ is not a tight family.

If one adds the hypotheses that $\inf_t \mu_t(E) \wedge \nu_t(E) > 0$ then the result is true however. In this case, define the measures $m_t = \mu_t(E)^{-1}\mu_t, n_t = \nu_t(E)^{-1}\nu_t$. From the additional assumption, it is straightforward to see that $m_t, m_t \ast n_t$ are tight families of probability measures. Hence, from what you already deduced, $n_t$ is a tight family of probability measures. Then, if $\sup_t n_t(K^c) < \varepsilon$ one has that $\sup_t \nu_t(K^c) < (\sup_t \nu_t(E)) \varepsilon \leq c \varepsilon$ where $c = \sup_t \|\nu_t\|$.

Comment: I'm sorry for my late response. Some other things draw my attention and I wasn't able to come back to this question until now. Do you see any chance it is "sufficient" (I'm not actually sure whether this is really a weaker assumption than what you are suggesting to assume in your answer) to assume that $\{\mu_t,\mu_t\ast\nu_t\}:t\in I\}$ is bounded in total variation norm?

Comment: Actually, I've just noticed that it's not even clear me why your rescaling argument can be applied. How do we need to deal with the left-hand side of $(2)$ in the general case? For clarity, I've asked a separate question for that: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4039050/47771. Please take a look.

Comment: I realised I'd made a typo and dropped a power $-1$ in my scratch argument that means things didn't quite work. My edit gives an extra assumption that is sufficient for this result and a counter-example showing you do need something stronger. You could almost certainly fiddle a bit to remove the assumption that $\nu_t(E)$ is bounded away from $0$ since small total mass only helps with tightness if that's something that would be useful for you.

Comment: Thank you for your edit! What are you assuming now precisely? Do you a priori assume that (a) $(\mu_t)_{t\in I}$ and $(\nu_t)_{t\in I}$ are tight or that (b) $(\mu_t)_{t\in I}$ and $(\mu_t\ast\nu_t)_{t\in I}$? And are you assuming that (c) $(\mu_t)_{t\in I}$ and $(\nu_t)_{t\in I}$ are bounded in total variation or that (d) $(\mu_t)_{t\in I}$ and $(\mu_t\ast\nu_t)_{t\in I}$ are bounded in total variation? I'd prefer to assume $(b)$ and $(d)$ instead of $(a)$ and $(c)$, if that's possible.

Comment: And can any of these conditions be inferred from your new assumption? BTW, can it be replaced by (e) $\inf_{t\in I}\mu_t(E)\wedge\inf_{t\in I}(\mu_t\ast\nu_t)(E)>0$?

Comment: I assume (b) and (c) alongside my additional hypothesis. My additional hypothesis and (b) are used to see that $(m_t)_{t \in I}, (m_t \ast n_t)_{t \in I}$ are tight which by your work implies that $(n_t)_{t \in I}$ is tight. We then need to see that this implies that $(\nu_t)_{t \in I}$ is tight. For this I use that $\sup_{t \in I} \nu_t(E) < \infty$. Filling in the details of this sketch is all just trivial inequality handling. Finally, I believe your (e) is just equivalent to my assumption since $\mu_t \ast \nu_t(E) = \mu_t(E) \nu_t(E)$.

Comment: Ah, however (b), (d) and (e) taken together work since (d) and (e) together imply (c). Indeed if $\sup_t \mu_t \ast \nu_t(E) = \sup_t \mu_t(E) \nu_t(E) < \infty$ and $ c = \inf_t \mu_t(E) > 0$ then $\sup_t \nu_t(E) = \sup_t \mu_t(E)\nu_t(E)\mu_t(E)^{-1} \leq c^{-1} \sup_t \mu_t(E) \nu_t(E)$.

Comment: I don't know - maybe I'm too stupid - but I'm not able to work the details out. As you wrote, this should be a simple rearranging task, but I'm not able to choose the constants appropriately. Please take a look of my edit. Are you really sure we are not missing something?

Comment: Since it seems like you know the answer, I'd be really thankful if you could provide an answer.

Comment: I did provide an answer. There is a sketch of a proof in the answer. You decided to do something that seems quite different in the attempt in the question and I don't have time to attempt to understand it and see if I can make it work. As I said, you should check that $\{m_t, m_t \ast n_t\}_{t \in I}$ is tight. Since these are probability measures, the work you did before implies that $\{n_t\}_{t \in I}$ is tight. Now try to deduce directly from this that $\{\nu_t\}_{t \in I}$ is tight. Which step in this is causing difficulties?

Comment: I've got it now. Your approach is easier to follow. And if I'm not missing something, we can drop the assumption that $(\mu_t)$ is uniformly bounded in total variation. All we need is that $(\mu_t)$ and $(\mu_t\ast\nu_t)$ are uniformly bounded away from $0$ in total variation and tight and that $(\mu_t\ast\nu_t)$ is uniformly bounded in total variation. Then $(\nu_t)$ is uniformly bounded in total variation and tight. Hopefully, I didn't miss something.