# Show that this family of measures is tight

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(\mu_t)_{t\in I}$ and $(\nu_t)_{t\in I}$ be families of finite signed measures on a metric vector space $E$ and $\mu_t\ast\nu_t$ denote the convolution of $\mu_t$ and $\nu_t$.

Assume $(\mu_t)_{t\in I}$ and $(\nu_t)_{t\in I}$ are bounded in total variation norm $\left\|\;\cdot\;\right\|$, i.e. $$c:=\max\left(\sup_{t\in I}\left\|\mu_t\right\|,\sup_{t\in I}\left\|\nu_t\right\|\right)<\infty,$$ and $(\mu_t)_{t\in I}$ and $(\mu_t\ast\nu_t)_{t\in I}$ are tight, i.e. for every $\varepsilon>0$, there is a compact $K_\varepsilon\subseteq E$ with $$\max\left(\sup_{t\in I}\mu_t(K_\varepsilon^c),\sup_{t\in I}(\mu_t\ast\nu_t)(K_\varepsilon^c)\right)<\varepsilon\tag1.$$

> Now I would like to show that $(\nu_t)_{t\in I}$ is tight as well, i.e. given $\varepsilon>0$, there is a compact $K\subseteq E$ with $\sup_{t\in I}\nu_t(K^c)<\infty$.

The obvious candidate is $K:=K_\varepsilon-K_\varepsilon$. We easily see \begin{equation}\begin{split}(\mu_t\ast\nu_t)(K_\varepsilon)&=\underbrace{\int_{K_\varepsilon}\mu_t({\rm d}x)\nu_t(\underbrace{K_\varepsilon-x}_{\subseteq\:K})}_{\le\:c\nu_t(K)}+\underbrace{\int_{K_\varepsilon^c}\mu_t({\rm d}x)\underbrace{\nu_t(K_\varepsilon-x)}_{\le\:1}}_{\le\:c\mu_t(K_\varepsilon^c)\:<\:\varepsilon}\\&<c\nu_t(K)+\varepsilon\end{split}\tag2\end{equation} for all $t\in I$.

> If $\mu_t=\nu_t(E)=1$, we easily obtain $$1-\varepsilon<(\mu_t\ast\nu_t)(K)<\nu_t(K)+\varepsilon\tag3$$ and hence $$\nu_t(K^c)=1-\nu_t(K)<2\varepsilon\tag4$$ for all $t\in I$. We should be able to do the same in the general case, but how do we need to deal with the left-hand side of $(2)$ then?

It clearly holds $(\mu_t\ast\nu_t)(E)\le\mu_t(E)\nu_t(E)$, but that doesn't seem to help much.