# If $\nu^{\ast 2}$ is a tight probability measure, is $\nu$ itself tight?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $E$ be a normed $\mathbb R$-vector space and $\mu$ be a *tight*$^1$ probability measure on $\mathcal B(E)$. Assume $\nu$ is another probability measure on $\mathcal B(E)$ and$^2$ $$\mu=\nu^{\ast k}\tag1$$ for some $k\in\mathbb N$.

> Are we able to show that $\nu$ is tight as well?

I know how we can prove that [the convolution of tight measures is tight](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3961257/47771) and how we can show that [if $\nu_1$ and $\nu_1\ast\nu_2$ are tight, then $\nu_2$ is tight as well](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3962461/47771), but I'm not sure how we could prove the desired claim here.

(To give some context: I would like to show that if $\mu$ is infinitely divisible (i.e. for all $n\in\mathbb N$, there is a probability measure $\nu_n$ such that $\mu=\nu_n^{\ast n}$) and tight, then the *convolution roots* $\mu^{\ast\frac1n}$ are well-defined for all $n\in\mathbb N$. In order to show uniqueness, we need that the $\nu_n$ are tight.)

---

$^1$ i.e. for all $\varepsilon>0$, there is a compact $K\in\mathcal B(E)$ with $\mu(K^c)<\varepsilon$.

$^2$ If $\nu_1,\ldots,\nu_k$ are measures on $\mathcal B(E)$ and $$\theta_k:E^k\to E\;,\;\;\;x\mapsto x_1+\cdots+x_k,$$ then the *convolution* of $\nu_1,\ldots,\nu_k$ is defined to be the pushforward measure $$\nu_1\ast\cdots\ast\nu_k:=\theta_k(\nu_1\otimes\cdots\otimes\nu_k)$$ of the product measure $\nu_1\otimes\cdots\otimes\nu_k$ with respect to $\theta_k$. If $\nu_1=\cdots=\nu_k$, we simply write $\nu_1^{\ast k}:=\nu_1\ast\cdots\ast\nu_k$.

Comment: It is a theorem bu Ulam that every Borel probability measure on a Polish space is tight (for example **Dudley, R. M.**, *Real Analysis and Probability*, Chapman & Hall,1989, section 7.1)

Comment: @OliverDiaz Yes, I know, but (as you say) we need to assume that $E$ is complete and separable for this. I think it should be possible to show the claim directly, given the stated assumptions.

Comment: What norm space are you working on?

Comment: @OliverDiaz You mean a concrete normed space in a certain application? For this question, I'm really interested in the given abstract scenario. (BTW, it would clearly be sufficient to prove the claim for $n=2$.)

Comment: @0xbadf00d are you sure you have a _normed space_ and not some metric space? Notice that a normed space of infinite dimension do not have compact sets without empty interior (i.e. every compact set has empty interior). Maybe you want probability measures on a Polish space (which I am sure can never be normed when the dimension is infinite).

Comment: @WillM. The $L^p$ spaces for $1 \leq p < \infty$ seem pretty Polish to me.

Comment: That is true, a normed space can be Polish for it just needs to be separable and there are plenty of examples. My bad.

Comment: How do you even define the convolution of two measures if the underlying space is not necessarily separable? It seems to me that the usual definitions run into some trouble in this setting.

Comment: What I mean is: If your space is not separable, you don't know that the Borel sigma algebra coincides with the product sigma algebra, so (as far as I see) you don't know that the map $\theta_k$ is measurable in a way that allows you to take the pushforward.

Comment: @WillM. The reason why I wrote "normed space", instead of something more general, is that we need a group structure in order to define the convolution and I didn't wanted to overcomplicate the question. My hope is that we can find a rather elementary argument (which might then can be adapted to more general situations).

Comment: @PhoemueX Why do you think that separability is needed to define the convolution? I gave the definition of the convolution in Footnote 2 and the same definition applies if $E$ is replaced by any [measurable group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_group) $(E,+)$.

Comment: @0xbadf00d the link you provide indeed assumes second countability of the topology, in metric spaces (in particular, normed spaces) this entails separability. So we ought to assume the space $\mathrm{E}$ is a separable normed space. In that case, _by definition_ the probability $\nu^{*k}$ is the distribution of the sum of $k$ independent $\mathrm{E}$-valued random objects each of which has measure $\nu.$ And me comment below (as a solution) is actually a proof.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comments, there are some potential issues for non-separable spaces, since then it might happen that the product sigma algebra on $E \times E$ is a strict subset of the Borel sigma algebra on $E \times E$. In this case, it is not clear that the map $\theta : E \times E \to E, (x,y) \mapsto x+y$ is measurable (with respect to the product sigma algebra), so that one can indeed define the convolution $\mu \ast \nu$ as the pushforward of the product measure $\mu \otimes \nu$ under $\theta$.

In the following, I therefore ignore some measurability issues. In case these are satisfied/resolved, I prove the following statement: If $\mu,\nu$ are probability measures on $E$ such that $\mu \ast \nu$ is tight, then $\mu$ and $\nu$ are tight as well. By symmetry, it suffices to show that $\nu$ is tight.

Since $\mu \ast \nu$ is tight, given $\epsilon > 0$, there is a compact set $K \subset E$ such that
$$
1-\epsilon
< \mu \ast \nu (K)
= \int_E \int_E 1_K (x+y) \, d \nu(y) \, d \mu(x)
= \int_E \nu(K-x) \, d \mu(x).
$$
This easily implies that there exists $x \in E$ such that $\nu(K-x) > 1 - \epsilon$. Since $K-x$ is compact and $\nu$ is a probability measure (so that $\nu(E \setminus (K - x)) < \epsilon$), we are done.

Answer (score 0):

**As mentioned in the comments, we must assume $\mathrm{E}$ is separable or else the convolution may not even be well-defined.**

Consider the probability space $(\mathrm{E}, \mathscr{B}_\mathrm{E}, \nu).$ On this probability space, the identity function $I_\mathrm{E}$ is an $\mathrm{E}$-valued random object whose distribution is $\nu.$ *A fortiori*, there exists random objects with law $\nu.$ Furthermore, $\nu^{*k}$ is, by definition, the law of $X_1 + \ldots + X_k$ where each the $(X_j)$ are jointly independent and each one of them has law $\nu.$ The function $\mathrm{E}^k \to \mathrm{E}$ given by $(e_1, \ldots, e_k) = e_1 + \ldots + e_k$ is continuous and as such, for a given compact set $\mathrm{K}$ of $\mathrm{E},$ the set $\mathrm{K} + \ldots + \mathrm{K}$ is also compact in $\mathrm{E}.$ Clearly,
$$
\bigcap\limits_{j = 1}^k \{X_j \in \mathrm{K} \} \subset \{X_1 + \ldots + X_k \in \mathrm{K} + \ldots + \mathrm{K}\}.
$$
As a consequence, by taking complements and using that the probability of a union is less or equal than the sum of the individual probabilities,
$$
\begin{align}
\nu^{*k}\left( (K + \ldots + K)^\complement \right) &= \mathbf{P}(X_1 + \ldots + X_k \notin \mathrm{K} + \ldots + \mathrm{K}) \\
&\leq \sum_{i = 1}^ k \mathbf{P}(X_i \notin \mathrm{K}) \\
&= k \nu \left( \mathrm{K}^\complement \right).
\end{align}
$$
Since $\nu$ is tight, for all $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a compact set $\mathrm{K}$ such that $\nu(\mathrm{K}) \geq 1 - \dfrac{\varepsilon}{k}$ and so,
$$
\nu^{*k}(\mathrm{K} + \ldots + \mathrm{K}) = 1 - k \nu \left( \mathrm{K}^\complement \right) \geq 1 - \varepsilon.
$$
Thus, $\nu^{*k}$ is also tight. Q.E.D.

*Scholium.* As I mentioned in the comments, I do not think that a tight probability measure on an infinite-dimensional normed space is very interesting for it has to assign total mass to a set of the form $\bigcup\limits_{n \in \mathbf{N}} \mathrm{K}_n$ where each $\mathrm{K}_n$ is a compact subset, and as such, it must have empty interior (it has to be very flat and perhaps finite-dimensional).

Comment: I don't understand the scholium.  The law of Brownian motion is a tight probability measure on $C([0,T];\mathbb{R}^{d})$ --- not finite dimensional, not flat, certainly interesting.

Comment: I've never done probability on Banach spaces but I am unsure how can something be tight and have full support in a infinite dimensional Banach space. When I read Convergence of Probability measure by Billings let I recall he had to define special metrics for the spaces C and D because compact sets for norms are just flat.

Comment: On the other hand, I know that _every_ probability measure on a Polish space is tight. So I am unexpectedly confused. Haha

Comment: Are you sure the special metrics weren't on $D$?  Anyway, tightness for Brownian motion follows from the fact that the path is uniformly Holder continuous with probability one.  (Remember compact sets in $C([0,T])$ are completely characterized by the Arzela-Ascoli Theorem.)  Any continuous function is approximable by uniformly Holder continuous functions so the tightness of BM doesn't contradict the fact that it's support equals $C([0,T])$.

Comment: @PeterMorfe yes, I went and check Billingsley book a few days ago. This again shows that geometry and probability don't like each other very much.